# Issues while creating a Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm trying to create a docker image using this command (removed the address as it's a company address):

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.web --build-arg _env=MTP-uat1 . -t Company/address:NlLogDownloadAl
```

But I keep getting this error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount745508724/Dockerfile.web: no such file or directory

Now I've gone through like 30 similar questions and followed what they say would fix it but it does no difference.

I have done the following:

- Changed the docker engine script buildkit from `true` to `false`.
- Made sure the directory I'm referring to has the `Dockerfile.web` file.
- Removed some things mentioned from the `.dockerignore` file.

I still get the same error all the time. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of the command *has to be context* (the directory where Docker should look for files / "the dot"):

```
Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

Try this one:

```
docker build \
    -f Dockerfile.web \
    --build-arg _env=MTP-uat1 \
    -t Company/address:NlLogDownloadAl \
    .
```

You are getting `no such file or directory` because you haven't specified the context properly, thus it probably cut off the last argument of the command `Company/address:NlLogDownloadAl` (or its part), treated it as a folder which probably doesn't even exist and then it tried to look up for `Dockerfile.web` which wouldn't exist too either due to invalid folder or just because of the wrong folder specified.